# I flagged an answer as spam. My flag was declined. Why?

Tags: discussion, spam

I flagged an answer as spam. It was declined and the message was:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

Here is the answer in question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7009720/8157693

Note the last part of the answer which is:

> [...] you'd be better off with something like WorldCitiesDatabase.Info.

The username for the person that posted the answer is WCD which I assumed was short for WorldCitiesDatabase.

I viewed the [user's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/887743/wcd) and they have this email listed on there

> info@worldcitiesdatabase.info

The answer does not indicate that this user is affiliated with WorldCitiesDatabase.Info (which is a paid service) and therefore falls into the spam category as defined by SO guidelines.

Why was my flag declined?

Comment: That answer looks useful to me, it only lacks attribution. Removing it would destroy some value. But you have a case as there is one other answer deleted as spam: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6458387/revisions for the same supplier .... so ... up to the mods ...

Comment: That's a fair point @rene and perhaps only the spammy bit can be removed in this case.

Comment: That whole question has been and is a spam magnet ...

Comment: It's ancient. Why should it matter all that much? I'd just edit in attribution and be done with it.

Comment: @Mithrandir that and the user is most likely not coming back ...

Comment: anyway we are better of if some mod delete it all, question included, these questions are only updated by spammers and do not make internet a better place

Comment: To answer your question a mod taught that the question was asking for that answer, not considering that it did have correct affiliation (I bet a custom mod flag indicating this would have been approved).

Comment: That looks more like improper self promotion than spam to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question asked for these types of resources. The answer that was flagged as spam provides three options

- MaxMind
- The high end version of World Cities Database
- A low end version of World Cities Database

The answer should provide disclosure that they are affiliated (which I've added), but in this case, this doesn't look like spam. It looks like an old resource request question from years ago that someone answered, who is affiliated with one of the potential products.

Comment: I agree better to custom mod flag and you can choose if you like to add attribution or delete, anyway in this case 10 community users solved the root problem.

Comment: While I normally would give someone the benefit of the doubt when providing useful resources that target the question, if you look at two of the other deleted answers there: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6458387/19679), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5954720/19679), you'll see that this person has been trying to spam this resource for years. In fact, I just deleted two other accounts from that same location that were promoting the same website. You wouldn't have had that context, but I recognized these folks from accounts I've previously destroyed. Looks like they refined their sales pitch.